# Why Docker restarts when no error is thrown and how to prevent it?

Tags: docker

When will Docker mark the inner service as failed without exiting a non zero code, and is there anyway to configure it not too do so?

I have a process running inside of docker, which is a python based server handling some heavy tasks. I found that if I send multiple request to it at the same time, although the memory is still quite OK, Docker will kind of thinks the inner process failed somehow (or something I don't know) -- it then restarts the service/container. I am guessing this is caused since the inner process is kind of stucked/not responding hence it gets marked as 'failed' -- I ran this server outside of docker and no error happened.

Also, if I use docker stack to deploy muiltiple replicas, it seems like when one of the replica is being restarted, all of the request to the service will get blocked till that replica recovers -- is it true? And is there anyway prevent this happen?

This is really annoying since the init steps of the server take quite some time...

Comment: What is the output of `docker logs -f <container-name>` ?

Comment: There are no extra logs. I actually found out what happened today. Apparently in some of the libs this python server uses there is some 'memory leak' like issues, so the the memory will just climb to a standard and at some point it triggers the oom to kill it -- and  I set the docker service as restart on failure -- and in this case somehow there are simply no logs (at least I didn't find and) about the process got killed.